# How to get informations corresponding FlexDock framework?

Tags: java, docking

I need some documentation or tutorials corresponding FlexDock framework.

For example:

- how to use dockbars?
- how to customize appearance of views?
- how to restrict docking between selected docking components and selected docking ports?
- is it possible to undock component to external floating window?